# Should an automatic transaxle be pressure flushed?

Tags: flush

The [statement](http://www.fordcontour.org/topic/10465-auto-tranny-fluidfilter-change-question/#entry58276) "Never pressure flush the CD4E..." worries me a bit.  Should it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never pressure flushed any drivetrain components. I have also ever heard of anyone else doing it, so I wouldn't recommend it. Most axles, transmissions, engines, and any other lubes I worked at for BMW were drain and fill. The also never pressure flush the coolant, or power steering.